# Is there a way to manually fire Google Maps events?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm writing a tooltip plugin for google maps, and it would make my life a lot easier if I were able to manually fire a google maps event in certain cases (for instance, the `mouseover` event for a certain marker).

Is there a way to do that?

(I'm using Google Maps V3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the trigger method in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Comment: Thanks - don't know how I missed that.